# How does Face Snapping work after Rotating Mesh in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, snapping

I'm trying to delve deep into Blender's 'snapping with' menu, and I got into a roadblock. I realized that with Face snapping set to *Closest*, if you rotate a mesh in *Edit Mode*, the face snapping in object mode will be skewed.

I'm not really looking for a solution, I'm trying to find out why this happens, and how Blender calculates face snapping.

[Sample Video](https://youtu.be/JQs5lPuVCdY)

Answer (score 1):

Solution!
In object mode, using 'closest', whether it be for face snapping or even vertex snapping, uses the closest vertex of the bounding box around your mesh, not the mesh itself. You can view the bounding box of your mesh in the object properties submenu, under viewport display.

So, what happens is that when you rotate a mesh in object mode, the bounding box rotates with it. However, in edit mode, since you're editing the mesh itself, the bounding box expands in one or more axis, without actually rotating. So when you go ahead and try to snap using closest mode, you'll actually be trying to snap with the closest vertex of the now expanded bounding box.

I highly suggest you play around with it and view the bounding box of your mesh to really understand what I mean.

Comment: By golly.. you're right! Learn something every day... :D